# IndexOutOfBoundsException not making sense to me

Tags: android, android-activity, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an IndexOutOfBoundsException, but I am protecting the call with finish() which should exit the Activity in Android!  Should I be using an else statement?

```
if (mIndex >= mQidList.size()) { 
  closeDB();
  finish();
}
mQidList.get(mIndex);
```

Comment: >= make this as only >

Comment: call finish() can't stand for that the later code can't be executed; you can add "return" after finish();

Comment: Both of the above are probably needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make following changes:

```
if (mIndex >= mQidList.size()) { 
  closeDB();
  finish();

  return;
} 
mQidList.get(mIndex);
```

When the condition becomes true, it means the size limit has reached so accessing/ trying to get data from any index beyond that will result in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

In your case when the finish is called, the activity is destroyed but the code is executed in top down pattern until all the method call entries from Stack are removed by returning from the called methods, thats why after finish, `mQidList.get(mIndex);` is executed which causes this exception.